# Disable/Enable Firebase Crashlytics during runtime

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

With Google sending out waves of warnings about the need to let users opt-in to crash reporting ([source](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/03/22/google-warning-developers-include-prominent-crash-reporting-disclosures-apps-face-removal/)) I'm trying to build an opt-in dialog for Firebase Crashlytics.

To be able to do this I would need to know whether Crashlytics is currently enabled (to decide whether to show the dialog or not). It seems `CrashlyticsCore.disabled` is responsible for tracking this but I haven't found any way to access the value because it's package private and doesn't have an accessor. How can I know during runtime if Firebase Crashlytics is enabled?

The second thing I'd need to do is disable crash reporting by default and enable it when the user agrees to opt-in. How I suspected to be able to do this:

AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
```

Activity:

```
boolean userAgrees = true;
CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(!userAgrees).build();
Fabric.with(this,  new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());

throw new RuntimeException("why doesn't this show up in Firebase Crashlytics?");
```

Why isn't my RuntimeException showing up in Firebase Crashlytics?

P.S. Crashlytics is working fine when removing these attempts to create an opt-in dialog.

Comment: Are you building with `crashlytics:2.9.1`?  Your code works for me when I use that version.  Also, during your testing, note that the crash isn't uploaded until the next app restart.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `2.9.1`. Can you see the crash report in the Firebase or the Fabric environment? Maybe it's a threading issue because I do throw the `RuntimeException` in the `onCreate` of the Activity so maybe I'm crashing my app while crashlytics is still uploading the previous crash on a different thread? I assumed it was uploaded through the Play Services so never thought about the next app restart. I Will do some more testing.

Comment: I see the crash in the Firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

It seems toggling Crashlytics will only take effect **after your app restarts**. `Fabric` is a singleton and all calls to its `Fabric.with` method will simply be ignored after it's been initialized. 
Source code below.

```
public static Fabric with(Context context, Kit... kits) {
    if (singleton == null) {
        Class var2 = Fabric.class;
        synchronized(Fabric.class) {
            if (singleton == null) {
                setFabric((new Fabric.Builder(context)).kits(kits).build());
            }
        }
    }

    return singleton;
}
```

One way around it is to keep track of the value yourself using `SharedPreferences` or other persistent storage methods and update your UI accordingly.

Comment: I understand how I can persist a boolean myself but I prefer not to because it's code clutter and if my boolean gets out of sync with the sdk because of a bug you're breaking the law.